# C++ templated static member constructor not being called

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, static, generic-programming

I have two test cases of a class having a static member instance. The first uses non-templated samples, while the second relies on generic object types.

*The dilemma is simple*: the constructor of the static member gets called before the main function (as it should), but only for the specific object types. The generic types do not exhibit the same behaviour. As the matter of fact, the constructor isn't compiled at all. It seems the compiler decided to completely overlook it as a means of (not completely justified) optimization.

I would like to know what is happening and what can be done to make it work in the most elegant way possible. I presume the obvious answer would be: use that static member somewhere in the code. I'd like not to do that, as the specific type case works without making use of that static member, apart from performing some "work" in its constructor.

The code samples:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////
// Specific case
//////////////////////////////////////////////
class CPassive
{
public:
    CPassive()
    {
        printf(" passively called ");
    }
};

class CActive
{
private:
    static CPassive ms_passive;
};
CPassive CActive::ms_passive;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// GENERIC TYPES
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class CSample
{
public:
    CSample()
    {
        printf("sample ");
    }
};

template <typename T>
class CGenericPassive
{
public:
    CGenericPassive()
    {
        T sample;
        printf(" generic passive .. ");
    }
private:
};

template <typename T>
class CGenericActive
{
private:
    static CGenericPassive<T> ms_passive;
};
template<typename T>
CGenericPassive<T> CGenericActive<T>::ms_passive;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    CActive activeExample;// instantiates the static member
    CGenericActive<CSample> activeExample; // obliterates the static from the class def.
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not fully understanding.  For the generic types, how many versions of the class are you expecting to run, and why are you expecting these versions to run and not an infinite number?


eg,
`CGenericPassive<int> CGenericActive<int>::ms_passive;` and `CGenericPassive<char***> CGenericActive<char***>::ms_passive;`

And what do you mean by "obliterates the static from the class"?

Comment: Whats the problem?  Is this code not doing what you think?  What is this codes output?  More specifically, what is this code doing that you need your education adjusted on?

Comment: @Dan the templated static member must be explicitly referenced in a non-templated function for it to be instanciated, whereas normal statics do not. I got an answer poi.ting this out, but it feels hackish or as if there's a quirk in c++'s rules.

Comment: You still have not defined what the problem is.  Is there a problem?  For the record, members are not instantiated.  Classes are.  If you dont call a member function then there is no need to for one to exist.  If you dont specialize a template then there is no need for that template specialization to exist.  But the code to instantiate MUST be generated if and when a class instance is created.

Comment: I have indeed defined what the problem is (but the question is long and full of sample code, so it may be boring and confusing at a first glance). Shortly put: why is that static member created/constructed only for non-templated classes, but it isn't for the templated one, even if an object of this container class type is created? It was not trivially obvious that this member will be discarded by the compiler (what rules did the compiler follow: non-directly used template code is discarded?). Thanks!

Comment: Members are NOT instantiated. PERIOD.  Show me what the output of this program is, and what you think the results should be.

Comment: @Dan See n.m.'s answer below, http://ideone.com/Y31PJA, specifically the full live example. Comment the `(void)ms_passive` member reference from that constructor and you'll see that `CGenericPassive`'s constructor won't be called at all, whereas the same thing doesn't happen if non-templated members are used. I was really tired when I wrote the "member instantiation" lexical item. Mind you, I'm not the only one "abusing" the expression: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fexplicit_instantiation.htm .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each (non-virtual) member of each class template you want instantiated needs to be referenced from non-template code, directly or indirectly. It is not enough to instantiate the class itself.

This is governed by the standard 14.7.1/2:

> Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist; in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist.

In your case it is enough to reference the member from `CGenericActive` constructor (you need to write this constructor obviously), like this:

```
CGenericActive()
 {
   // just reference it so it gets instantiated
   (void)ms_passive;
 }
```

[Full live example](http://ideone.com/Y31PJA).

Comment: Thanks! That's a workaround I also tried, but it felt hackish. I guess I'll have to delegate more logic to the static member for it to function more transparently and reliably in order not to confuse a third party programmer. BTW: is there any C++ rule that determines this behavior? The same as for the templated code: if not used anywhere, it won't (obviously) be generated and compiled? (because, intuitively, it seems so, even if the member's class constructor is doing some work that shouldn't get optimized away).

Comment: Added reference to the standard chapter and verse.